# HSQLDB - Date Format : Incompatible data type in conversion or invalid datetime format

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, hsqldb, dbunit

I'm doing integration testing in a Hsqldb. My production database is an Oracle Database.

### Versions

```
Hibernate : 4.1.3.final.

Hsqldb : 2.3.3. ( I can't use the 2.3.4 because it can't run all my junit tests in one click.)
```

### My problems

I met two different exceptions when I had to test methods that contains queries where the `WHERE` condition asks a date :

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data types in combination
```

or

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

**Codes that caused the exception**

The code below caused the first exception (incompatible data types in combination)

```
 select = "from Player player where player.creationDate = to_char(sysdate,'dd/MM/yy')"
```

The code below caused the second exception (invalid datetime format)

```
 select = "from Player player where player.creationDate > '01/01/2016'"
```

### How I tried to fix this

1) So obviously, the problem stems from the date format. Hsqldb supports the `'yyyy-MM-dd'` date format so when I changed `to_char(sysdate,'dd/MM/yy')` and `01/01/2016` into `1995-01-01`, it worked fine.

However, I can't change the date format of these methods.

2) On second thoughts, I considered changing the hsqldb source code, but it seemed a little bit radical.

Are there any options than the latter?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: use named parameters and use setDate function instead

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `varchar`?

Comment: I'm not.
to_char(date,'fmt') is an Oracle function that allows me to display a date in another format. (the default format is : dd-mon-yy) Since my oracle database uses dd/MM/yy, I had to use this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont try to format the date. Use query with named parameters instead.
Then you can use setters for all data types. See example below:

```
String hql = "from Player player where player.creationDate = :date";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setDate("date", new Date()).list();
```